# Equivalent of pandas 'clip' in Julia

Tags: julia

In pandas, there is the `clip` function (see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html), which constrains values within the lower and upper bound provided by the user. What is the Julia equivalent? I.e., I would like to have:

```
> clip.([2 3 5 10],3,5)
> [3 3 5 5]
```

Obviously, I can write it myself, or use a combination of `min` and `max`, but I was surprised to find out there is none. `StatsBase` provides the `trim` and `winsor` functions, but these do not allow fixed values as input, but rather counts or percentiles (https://juliastats.github.io/StatsBase.jl/stable/robust.html).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are probably looking for `clamp`:

```
help?> clamp

  clamp(x, lo, hi)

  Return x if lo <= x <= hi. If x > hi, return hi. If x < lo, return lo. Arguments are promoted to a common type.
```

This is a function for scalar `x`, but we can broadcast it over the vector using dot-notation:

```
julia> clamp.([2, 3, 5, 10], 3, 5)
4-element Array{Int64,1}:
 3
 3
 5
 5
```

If you don't care about the original array you can also use the in-place version `clamp!`, which modifies the input:

```
julia> A = [2, 3, 5, 10];

julia> clamp!(A, 3, 5);

julia> A
4-element Array{Int64,1}:
 3
 3
 5
 5
```

Comment: Thank you! I had never heard before of the word "clamp". For anyone else reading this, the function is in base Julia, and the docs can be found here: https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/stdlib/math/#Base.Math.clamp

Comment: Quick question: how would I implement this on a vector with missing values in it? I.e., it seems I need `skipmissing`, but then all the missings are gone, while I would like to preserve those.

Comment: Perhaps something like `map(x -> x === missing ? x : clamp(x, 3, 5), [2, 3, 5, 10, missing])`

Comment: Thank you, that works nicely. If prefer the `ismissing()` syntactically, but with the three equality signs also works indeed